# ASP MVC Razor foreach inside Javascript block

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a Partial View that returns a Javascript function call after I submit an Ajax form.  It takes a list of addresses and call Javascript functions to geocode and place markers on a Google Map.  When I compile the following code, I get "Conditional compilation is turned off" error around var in the ForEach line.

```
@model IEnumerable<TestStore.Models.Address>

@if (Model.Count() > 0)
{
<script type="text/javascript">
    deleteMarkers();

    @foreach(var item in Model)
    {
        codeAddress('@item.GetAddress');
    }  
</script>
}
```

I fiddle around with the code and the following does work without compile errors:

```
@if (Model.Count() > 0)
{
<script type="text/javascript">
    deleteMarkers();
</script>

    foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <script type="text/javascript">
            codeAddress('@item.GetAddress');
        </script>
    }
}
```

For sake of discussion, if I have longer logic that make a lot of Javascript function calls inside loops, I would much prefer to surround everything inside 1 script block. I searched around Stack Overflow and it seem that Razor syntax could go inside a script block but I don't know how that look like in my example.

Answer (score 48):

Or you can use the `@:` syntax instead of the `<text>` element in your loop. [Here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/15/asp-net-mvc-3-razor-s-and-lt-text-gt-syntax.aspx) is a tutorial.

```
@:codeAddress(@item.GetAddress);
```

Comment: even after so long is still very useful

Answer (score 21):

its because the javascript inside your for loop looks like C# code to Razor. Wrap it in `<text>`. In general any block content `{ /* this is block content */ }` should always have a single html node - or if you dont need an html node (like in your case) you can use `<text>`

```
@foreach(var item in Model)
{
    <text>codeAddress('@item.GetAddress');</text>
}
```